# Search by exact text in xpath selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a question regarding xpath.
I try to locate the element that is in a drop down for example Surveys
when I try to search using contains it is working

```
//li[contains(text(),'Surveys')]
```

But when I tried to search exact it is failed

```
//li[text()='Surveys']
```

Can someone please advise?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text **Surveys** have a lot of white-spaces around it. So alternatively to suppress the white-spaces you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
//li[normalize-space()='Surveys']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `normalize-space` to remove whitespace characters:

```
//li[normalize-space(.)='Surveys']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "exact match" is missing the "new line" character, "\n". Try:

```
//li[text()='Surveys\n']
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it before, but you can try a newer way, I am still using it and it is working fine

right click --> copy XPath --> fix `" "`